# How to best implement a list of 'monsters' in Java?

Tags: java, list, implementation

Let's say I want to have a list of Monsters. Each of these monsters has similar sets of attributes to them, a few of which are these:

```
String name;
int[] stats;
int[] attackRange;
int defense;
int health;
```

Every monster has their own value of these stats, but they all have them. For example, one monster type might be this:

```
name = "Slime";
stats = [3, 0, 1, 1];
attackRange = [1, 2, 3];
defense = 1;
health = 5;
```

Now, say I have a class called 'Fight' that basically initiates an instance of combat.
The player's stats are loaded in, and I want to be able to also load in the stats of at least 1 instance of a monster, i.e. a Slime with the stats mentioned above, and a Giant Bat, which would have its own version of the stats mentioned above.

For some reason, I'm having a hard time figuring out an efficient way of approaching this. One idea would be to have each monster type to be a subclass of a Monster class, like

```
class Slime extends Monster
```

But considering there's going to be lots of different types of monsters, I don't know how cumbersome/'clunky' that idea might be to implement. Another way is to have an array of all the monsters and select it via a selector index, such as

```
public void loadMonster(int index){
    switch(index){
      case 0: name = "Slime"; stats = [3, 0, 1, 1]; //and so on with the rest of the attributes
}
```

and then call that several times to load, but it'd be awkward and hard to read if I put all the stats of every monster into one switch statement.

Comment: It depends a lot on if you want to generate monsters on the fly and have random encounters, or if you want to pre-bake every interaction. Personally, I would make a Monster class and extend it for each of the types to reduce duplicate code as much as possible, however, I don't know the scope and depth of your project. The benefit of creating a Monster class is that you can add methods to decrease/increase health and all sorts of things, the Player themselves could extend the monster class and just add additional inventory methods for example.

Comment: Personally, I'd start with a base line `interface`, which represents all the properties that EVERY `Monster` MUST have.  You can then expand on "specialised" functionality via other `interfaces`, like `Flyable`, `Swimmable`, etc...

Comment: If there are lots of monsters and they have the same properties then I'd create one Monster class, and a way to load the monsters from a Java resource or even file. Then you can keep the monster definition out of the code. In other words, I would treat them as **data**, not source code. Java properties would work, or maybe JSON or XML.

Comment: I should clarify, I intend to have at least, say, 30 monsters, and I want the interactions to be procedural. For example, this area would have these kinds of monsters, and the number and difficulty would depend on the difficulty setting, so kind of a controlled random if that makes sense.
If I do have an extended class for every monster type, would I have a constructor for each subclass and set the data in the constructor? Would that be possible?

Comment: So an update, I figured out for now a decent route for me.
`
public class Monster {
    protected String name;
    protected int[] stats;
    protected int[] attackRange;
    protected int defense;
    protected int health;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getDefense() {
        return defense;
    }
    public int[] getAttack() {
        return attackRange;
    }
    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
}
`
Then have each monster type be a subclass like I was thinking, with constructors setting those values.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a list of Monster classes. Each monster would have its own instance of Monster and would be added into the list. If a monster need additional attributes like speed or special attack, then you could extend the Monster base class. In the Fight class, you would have a loadPlayer() and loadMonster() method. You would pass in the index of the monster you wanted to fight. An initiateCombat() in the Fight class would begin the melee.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean exactly. Could you give an example?